# Lack of plasticity of Moly wire

Tags: stress-strain

during re-coiling of tungsten coil wound with moly mandrel ,the mandrel is breaking in between(the mandrel is annealed before) :
we don't know what exactly is causing as some length works fine and in some length it is breaking .
we are getting suggestions that this causes by either Lack of plasticity, or  it is caused by high heterogeneity of Moly wire.
I am not familiar with either of these topics , can you share your knowledge on these topics please so that i can understand them better.

Comment: Wound on a molybdenum mandrel? Which is the wire and which is the mandrel? Moly is bcc so doesn’t have good slip systems. If temperature cycling the assembly be careful of differing thermal expansion.

Comment: I am very sorry for my late reply..A 250 mic molybdenum wire is the mandrel..on top of it 180 mic tungsten wire is wound... actually I need to know what these topics "lack of elasticity"and "high heterogeneity"means.. and  why it is important.